# Behavior of member function changes when an object is passed to it?

Tags: c++, class

I was implementing linked lists using classes, and I found something that I can't explain. Here is the code:

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

class LinkedList{
    public:
        int msize = 0;
        Node *head;
        Node *tail;
        void append(Node mynode){
            if(msize == 0){
                head = &mynode;
                tail = &mynode;
                msize++;
            }
            else{
                (*tail).next = &mynode;
                tail = &mynode;
                msize++;
            }
        }
        void mergeList(LinkedList l2){
            cout << (*head).data;
        }
   };
```

The problem that I am facing is with the mergeList function, which takes another linked list as an input. Now, here is the code in the main function:

```
int main(){
    LinkedList l1;
    LinkedList l2;

    Node n1 , n2;
    n1.data = 132;
    n2.data = 123;

    l1.append(n1);
    l2.append(n2);

    l1.mergeList(l2);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the problem: In the function `mergeList`, the value being outputted is 1, whereas it should be 132, since `n1` is the head node of linked list `l1`. If  I define the prototype of `mergeList` as `void mergeList()` instead of `void mergeList(LinkedList l2)`, then it works fine. Why does it happen when I pass a linked list to the function?

Comment: Your function takes a *copy* of the node - all those `&mynode` take the address of a local variable that goes out of scope (and you are therefore storing dangling pointers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    void append(Node mynode){
        if(msize == 0){
            head = &mynode;
```

Here you're storing the address of `mynode`, which is a local variable in `append` (it's a function parameter). By the time `append` returns, its local variables are destroyed (including `mynode`), so now your `head` points to a variable that no longer exists.

Trying to use `head` later causes undefined behavior.